# Adding field in attribute table on several layers using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have about twenty separate polygon-layers, all consisting of almost - but not entirely, the same information in their current attribute tabels. However, now I want to add a field in the attribute table all of the layers.

I don't want to merge the layers and I'm thinking that there must be a smoother way to do it beside adding one field at a time in each layer.

Can I perhaps use the ModelBuilder?

Update:

[image]

Right now, I'm just testing with one layer, thinking I can use the same model later. But for some reason this doesn't turn out quite right.

The first steps works fine, adding fields to the original layer. After that I'm intersecting the layer with three other layers to be able to calculate the fields, but this is were something goes wrong and it's like the field calculator calculates the wrong fields for some reason.

Comment: What does your model so far look like?

Comment: Yes you can use ModelBuilder. When you get the model working on one feature class you can use then use Iterate Feature Classes to execute it on all feature classes: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-classes.htm